# Push multiple objects into an jQuery array

Tags: jquery, arrays

There are two arrays contains objects like as follow:

```
        var departmentArray=[{DepartmentId:1,DeparmentTitle:Dept1},{DepartmentId:2,DeparmentTitle:Dept2},{DepartmentId:3,DeparmentTitle:Dept3}];

    var employeesArray = [{EmpId:1,EmpName:Raj,DepartmentId:1},{EmpId:2,EmpName:Ravi,DepartmentId:1},{EmpId:3,EmpName:Ram,DepartmentId:1},{EmpId:4,EmpName:Rajesh,DepartmentId:2},{EmpId:5,EmpName:Rahim,DepartmentId:2}];

var departmentAndEmployeeDetails = {
   this.DepartmentId = 0;
   this.DepartmentTitle = '';
   this.EmployeeId = 0;
   this.EmployeeName = '';
}

var departmentAndEmployeeArray = [];

for(var i=0;i<departmentArray.length;i++)
{
    var currentEmployees = [];
    var empDepartmentItem = new departmentAndEmployeeDetails();
    empDepartmentItem.DepartmentId = departmentArray[i].DepartmentId;
    empDepartmentItem.DepartmentTitle = departmentArray[i].DeparmentTitle;

    currentEmployees = $.grep(employeesArray,function(empItem,index){
    return (empItem.Department==departmentArray[i].DepartmentId);
    });

    if(currentEmployees.length>0)
    {
       for(var j=0;j<currentEmployees.length;j++)
       {
           empDepartmentItem.EmployeeId = currentEmployees[j].EmpId;
           empDepartmentItem.EmployeeName = currentEmployees[j].EmpName;
           departmentAndEmployeeArray.push(empDepartmentItem);
       }
    }
    else
    {
        departmentAndEmployeeArray.push(empDepartmentItem); 
    }
}
```

After executing the above code i got following result:
The departmentAndEmployeeArray contains the following items.

```
departmentAnEmplyoeeArray = [{DepartmentId:1,DepartmentTitle:Dept1,EmployeeId:3,EmployeeName:Emp3}, {DepartmentId:1,DepartmentTitle:Dept1,EmployeeId:3,EmployeeName:Emp3}, {DepartmentId:1,DepartmentTitle:Dept1,EmployeeId:3,EmployeeName:Emp3}, {DepartmentId:2,DepartmentTitle:Dept2,EmployeeId:5,EmployeeName:Emp5}, {DepartmentId:2,DepartmentTitle:Dept2,EmployeeId:5,EmployeeName:Emp5}];
```

But expected result is following one.

```
departmentAnEmplyoeeArray = [{DepartmentId:1,DepartmentTitle:Dept1,EmployeeId:1,EmployeeName:Emp1}, {DepartmentId:1,DepartmentTitle:Dept1,EmployeeId:2,EmployeeName:Emp2}, {DepartmentId:1,DepartmentTitle:Dept1,EmployeeId:3,EmployeeName:Emp3}, {DepartmentId:2,DepartmentTitle:Dept2,EmployeeId:4,EmployeeName:Emp4}, {DepartmentId:2,DepartmentTitle:Dept2,EmployeeId:5,EmployeeName:Emp5}];
```

Actually what happens here is, in the currentEmployees array loop the last employee details will replaces the previous employee details after pushing the data into the array.

When the second iteration happend in departmentArray and pushed elements into the result array then the previous existed items values replaced by last item values.

Thanks in advance to your help

Comment: according to your expected output, why dont you loop through employees

Comment: I want all the department details. So I loop departments array first.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are having a loop where you need a new object in that loop just create a clone of that object using [object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
Right now you are just pushing the same object into the loop on each iteration

```
for(var j=0;j<currentEmployees.length;j++)
{
   let empDeptItem = Object.assign({}, empDepartmentItem);
   empDeptItem.EmployeeId = currentEmployees[j].EmpId;
   empDeptItem.EmployeeName = currentEmployees[j].EmpName;
   departmentAndEmployeeArray.push(empDeptItem);
}
```

Comment: For all browsers we can user $.extend({},empDepartmentItem); in jQuery. It's working as expected in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

@JoshKisb answer is working fine in some browsers but not in IE browser. So to working this in all browsers we can use the **$.extend** instead of **Object.assign** in **jQuery** like as follows:

```
for(var j=0;j<currentEmployees.length;j++)
{
   let empDeptItem = $.extend({}, empDepartmentItem);
   empDeptItem.EmployeeId = currentEmployees[j].EmpId;
   empDeptItem.EmployeeName = currentEmployees[j].EmpName;
   departmentAndEmployeeArray.push(empDeptItem);
}
```

Hope this helps to others.